# delete from mysql table using both where and where in conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It might be simple question, but i am not good with mysql queries.

im trying this query to delete certain items from table but getting error.
Here is the query:

```
DELETE FROM sys_forms_in_groups WHERE FormID IN (6,7,23,41) AND WHERE GroupID = 2
```

Here is the error i am getting.

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where GroupID = 2' at line 1
```

This is the table where i want to delete the records from.
[image]

Comment: SQL is talking to you `near` => `'where GroupID`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a superfluous `WHERE` on your clauses:

```
DELETE FROM sys_forms_in_groups WHERE FormID IN (6,7,23,41) AND WHERE GroupID = 2
                                                                 ^ here
```

**Remove** that and it should be fine.